# Referencing an Embedded Resource from UWP XAML

Tags: c#, uwp, embedded-resource

I am trying to find a way to reference a Embedded Resource from XAML in UWP, but so far I am unsuccessful. I have tried the common ways:

```
<Image Source="pack:,,,/MyLibrary;Component/File.png" />
```

and

```
<Image Source="/MyLibrary;Component/File.png" />
```

Same goes for fonts:

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" FontFamily="/MyLibrary;Component/Test.ttf#Font Name" />
```

None of these seems to work. The path is underlined as invalid in case of `Image.Source`, while it is not underlined in `FontFamily` - but still does not work in either case. I know this has worked in WPF and I am thinking this syntax is not supported in UWP but I can't find any source stating this.

I know it is possible to load embedded resources from code, but in this case I am specifically interested if there is an equivalent syntax available in XAML as well.

Comment: Have you tried this ? var assembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var resource = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("resourceName");   So if your project is called 'MyApp', and the path to your file is '/Resources/abc.png', resourceName would be:

"MyApp.Resources.abc.png"

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have specified this. I know we can reference resources from code, but I wanted to know if there is a equivalent XAML syntax available. I will update my question :-)

Comment: Do you want use only embeddedresource or any other build action ?

Comment: I would like to know for `Embedded Resource`. I know it works with `Content` files correctly using `ms-appx`. This question is mostly out of curiosity as I am unable to find any resources pointing me in either direction (supported/not supported)

Comment: What did you choose in "Copy to output directory" option?

Comment: I have tried None and Copy Always

Comment: Any solution for this? I also wanted to get an `Embedded Resource` from `xaml`