# Content Build Action for Resource Files in the Uno Platform

Tags: c#, uwp, uno-platform

I have warnings building an Uno Platform app. Summarized, the warnings appear as below:

```
...\Source\Resources\Icon-256.svg : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
...\Source\Properties\Default.rd.xml : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
```

It seems the Uno Platform doesn't support the Content build action at all. However, there are two parts:

1. What to do about the 'Default.rd.xml' file. This is automatically created by UWP projects and is required for the builds. In Uno/Xamarin this warning can safely be ignored. I'm sure there is a way to exclude it from the project file for Uno as well.
2. The `Icon-256.svg` file **is** required and is referenced in XAML as below. I do need to find a way to include this file in the assembly.

   ```
   <Image Source="ms-appx:///Resources/LogoIconBlue-256.svg" />
   ```

The first idea for a solution would be to simply change the build action to Embedded Resource. This is what was even recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131778/getfilefromapplicationuriasync-copyasync-asstreamforread-not-implemented-in-un/58141194#58141194). However, I do not believe UWP supports using embedded resources in XAML like WPF did. In fact Martin already asked that and no solutions were found [Referencing an Embedded Resource from UWP XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667799/referencing-an-embedded-resource-from-uwp-xaml).

So what is the 'official' recommendation for handling this situation? I would prefer not to fall back into loading the image using code-behind but I expect that might be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is caused by [Xamarin.Android itself](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/fcd7cf8f4200ccae92e333c920613bfec260973b/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets#L770) as it does not know what to do with `Content` items.

This has been fixed in Uno 3.1 with the support of the `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()` method, which removes `Content` items to transform them into `AndroidAsset` items.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing this in an Android Build output. So with Uno 3.1 Content build action is supported by automatically converting to an Android Asset. Then in Xaml I can access it normally with an application URI as that method is now supported. Bottom line: with Android 3.1 this is all supported without any code changes from UWP? Or do I still need something special to package an android asset working around Xamarin?